# Can we say 'I'm seeing a lot of (someone's name)'?

Tags: grammar

This question came to me while I was reading an example sentence, a standalone sentence, about *repeated actions just around the moment* from *Oxford Grammar*.

The original sentence is:

> Jake's seeing a lot of Felicity these days.

Since the letter *f* is in capital, I suppose that's a someone's name and I've seen that name is owned by a book's writer, so I'm sure it's a name not a [noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/felicity). Although, that's what I was thinking and after looking up the word and turns out it's countable noun and the word *Felicity* above doesn't have **es**.

Anyway, does that highlighted sentence above have the same meaning with this sentence below:

> Jake's seeing Felicity a lot these days.

This is my first time I've seen *a lot of* is used together with someone's name. That's what I want to confirm here whether my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable. However, you should be aware of the potential for double entendre.  "Seeing a lot of" can mean "being around them a lot." For example, you could be coworkers or classmates etc., such that you are frequently in the same location.

On the other hand, there is a scene from a popular TV show that goes a little like this.
George: You seem to be seeing a lot of Nurse Mary these days.
Edmund: Almost all of her, in fact.

By which he is implying that there are erotic things going on.

Your alternative form makes this ribaldry much more difficult to infer. You might even go so far as to say "frequently" or "often" instead of "a lot." But where is the fun in that?

Comment: +1 for 'Almost all of her'.